# How to send email with ckeditor without Html tags

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, symfony-forms, swiftmailer

I have integrated ckeditor in my project symfony for sending emails.

I have added this in Form builder

```
->add('message', CKEditorType::class)
```

CKEditor its work and i see the toolbar
but when i send email, I receive the message like this exemple

```
<p>Hello,</p>
<p><strong> This is an example</strong></p>
```

My problem is i don't what to receive the message with html tags, i want to receive it like this

> Hello
>   **This is an example**

Comment: Looks like you're sending a HTML text as a plain text email. You should send it as a HTML email. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you, i have added message as a html : ->setBody(
                     
                        $message,'text/html'
                    )

Comment: show us where you send the email

Answer (score 1):

You can use twigs raw filter, so in the template where it's rendered use:

```
{{ message|raw }}
```

This will render your CKEditor tags like strong.

You can read more on this [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer, but be sure the content of the email is from a trusted user. This can lead to lots of security issues if the content is provided by untrusted users. https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.md#validating-rich-user-content